# Dynamic breadcrumb position in css

Tags: html, css, breadcrumbs

I have a breadcrumb.The demo link can be seen [here](http://jsfiddle.net/santoshkumar/qgsTN/). I want my breadcrumbs to look exactly like the referenced image.

The fiddle code is like this

```
<nav class="woocommerce-breadcrumb" itemprop="breadcrumb">

<span><a class="home" href="http://localhost/WebSites/Mkratom/Website">Home</a></span>
<span><a href="http://localhost/WebSites/Mkratom/Website/shop/">Shop</a> </span>  
<span><a href="http://localhost/WebSites/Mkratom/Website/product-category/fictation/">Fictationssss</a></span> 
<span>Moon Shiningsssssss</span>
</nav>
```

Note that my referenced image is a dynamic one, so I can put any length of text. Text length can vary in different places so kindly keep that in mind.
Any help and suggestions will be really appreciated.

Thanks.

[image: Dynamic Breadcrumb images]

**Update**

Sorry I can't change my markup as it is coming from the database.

Comment: It would probably be easier if you had one class that was .active, then you could move .active from one breadcrumb to the next. Unless you cant. Your absolute postions IMO are the problem. You need something that is a little easier to control. Are there any constraints on the project?

Comment: tip : background gradient or absolute pseudo-elements.

Answer (score 0):

From tips given earlier :) , here is a possibility

http://codepen.io/gcyrillus/pen/Eyrjv

with pseudo-element and last-child.